# Sephardic Wedding Custom: Avram Siz Reading

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, wedding, nusach-edot-hammizrach

What are the verses one reads to fulfill the Sephardic custom of Avram Siz?

Avram Siz (or Avraham Zaqein) is the Sephardic custom of reading a passage in Genesis the Shabbat following a wedding.

Comment: I always assumed it was all of Genesis 24 (ie. from parsha break to parsha break)

Comment: @DoubleAA I have always assumed the same but I would love to have a source to cite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arukh (under [*Chatan*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42537&st=&pgnum=199)) mentions reading 3 verses (ie. Genesis 24:1-3). The Tashbetz (2:39) says the local custom near him is like the Arukh.

The Avudarham (at the end of the [Laws of Wedding Blessings](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=195)) citing Rav Sa'adya Gaon's Siddur (though I can't find it there) writes to recite until "MiSham" (ie. Genesis 24:1-7). The Magen Avraham (144 sk 5) and Kaf HaChayim ([144 sk 10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=283)) cite this version as well. [Berit Kehuna](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8751&st=&pgnum=95) cites that practice as the custom in Djerba.

The [Tikkun Yissakhar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21647&st=&pgnum=208) posits that the remainder of the Parsha is not read since it is only a Minhag.

[This modern rendition of the section on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JkWl4b-PsE) contains Genesis 24:1-7.

Comment: The Tashbetz's quote of the Arukh is off and doesn't explicitly say the reading is 3 verses long. I wonder if there was a printing error in our editions of the Arukh (it would have to be old since my link is to possibly the editio princeps, I think), and really the Tashbetz is thinking the Arukh is saying 7.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8834&st=&pgnum=639 algeria like djerba unsurprisingly

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://delphiresearchgroup.com/b2evolution/index.php?title=the_sefardic_wedding_different_than_what&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) mentions:

> the Avram Siz includes the reading of a passage in Genesis in which
>   Abraham sends his servant, Eliezer, to find a suitable mate for his
>   son, Isaac. This is why it's called the "Avram Siz," which is Aramaic
>   for "Avram was old," which are the words that introduce this Torah
>   passage, which is read not in Hebrew, but in Aramaic, the language of
>   the Targum, the Aramaic translation of the Torah.

It seems, then, that all of Breishit 24 is meant as that entire chapter deals with Eliezer finding a wife for Yitzhak.

Comment: Yes that was the impression I had but I would love a very specific source.

Comment: @Aaron it's tough to find sources on the web regarding this practice. However, I'm inferring from the above that when he says "passage", he would mean the entire chapter. I can't think of why any verses in the chapter might be eliminated as it would detract from the story. I don't get to be invited to many Sephardi weddings. Perhaps, I can contact one of my Sephardi friends and ask him what occurred at his wedding.

Comment: Looks like DoubleAA found the sources. Looks like it's way shorter than the whole chapter.